Proxy MQTT-Over-TLS to AWS IoT Core
My goal is to proxy traffic between a device and AWS IoT core through a local machine so I can inspect the traffic in wireshark. How would I achieve this goal? I own the device hardware and source code.
This is what I have running currently, everything in the middle column is running on a local Ubuntu 24.04 machine.
                  
                  |------------|
      ----------->| DNS Server |
      |           |------------|
      |                 
      |                
     \ /
|-----------|     |------------|     |--------------|
| My Device |<--->| MITM Proxy |<-X->| AWS IoT Core |
|-----------|     |------------|     |--------------|
                        |
                        | <-- Decrypted TLS traffic
                        |
                       \ /
                  |-----------|
                  | Wireshark |
                  |-----------|
                       

I have a DNS server set up to resolve the AWS endpoint to my local machine, I see the traffic arriving at my machine.
The traffic between my device and AWS is using TLS 1.2 with an X509 certificate & private key.
My device uses MBEDTLS and is currently set up to not verify SSL certificates.
I expected this to be a fairly simple task but after two days here is what I have tried:

Burp Suite Community Edition
Burp Suite Community Edition NoPE Extension
MITMProxy Transparent mode with and without mitmproxy-mqtt-script
MITMProxy Reverse Proxy mode

I think a lot of my problem is these tools are built for HTTP/HTTPS traffic with CONNECT and other HTTP headers which are not present in raw MQTT over TLS.
The closest I have gotten to this working was using MITMProxy in reverse proxy mode with the following command:
mitmproxy --mode reverse:tls://{AWS ACCOUNT NUMBER}-ats.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:8883 --tcp-hosts '.*' --listen-port 8883 --showhost --set client_certs=./certs/{AWS ACCOUNT NUMBER}-ats.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com.pem

where the .pem file contained the client cert and private key in the following format
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
<private key>
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
<cert>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

which gives the following log output in mitmproxy:
info: [15:44:41.196][192.168.1.200:52433] client connect
info: [15:44:41.271][192.168.1.200:52433] server connect {AWS ACCOUNT NUMBER}-ats.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:8883 ([2406:da00:ff00::3415:cd0c]:8883)
error: [15:44:41.583] Addon error: Cannot load TLS client certificate: [('DECODER routines', '', 'unsupported'), ('asn1 encoding routines', '',
'wrong tag'), ('asn1 encoding routines', '', 'nested asn1 error'), ('asn1 encoding routines', '', 'nested asn1 error'), ('SSL routines', '', 'PEM
lib')]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aaron-decker/.pyenv/versions/3.12.3/envs/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/mitmproxy/net/tls.py", line 173, in
create_proxy_server_context
    context.use_privatekey_file(client_cert)
  File "/home/aaron-decker/.pyenv/versions/3.12.3/envs/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1138, in use_privatekey_file
    self._raise_passphrase_exception()
  File "/home/aaron-decker/.pyenv/versions/3.12.3/envs/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1114, in
_raise_passphrase_exception
    _raise_current_error()
  File "/home/aaron-decker/.pyenv/versions/3.12.3/envs/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py", line 57, in
exception_from_error_queue
    raise exception_type(errors)
OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('DECODER routines', '', 'unsupported'), ('asn1 encoding routines', '', 'wrong tag'), ('asn1 encoding routines', '', 'nested
asn1 error'), ('asn1 encoding routines', '', 'nested asn1 error'), ('SSL routines', '', 'PEM lib')]

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aaron-decker/.pyenv/versions/3.12.3/envs/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/mitmproxy/addons/tlsconfig.py", line 286, in
tls_start_server
    ssl_ctx = net_tls.create_proxy_server_context(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/aaron-decker/.pyenv/versions/3.12.3/envs/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/mitmproxy/net/tls.py", line 176, in
create_proxy_server_context
    raise RuntimeError(f"Cannot load TLS client certificate: {e}") from e
RuntimeError: Cannot load TLS client certificate: [('DECODER routines', '', 'unsupported'), ('asn1 encoding routines', '', 'wrong tag'), ('asn1
encoding routines', '', 'nested asn1 error'), ('asn1 encoding routines', '', 'nested asn1 error'), ('SSL routines', '', 'PEM lib')]
error: [15:44:41.583][192.168.1.200:52433] No TLS context was provided, failing connection.
warn: [15:44:41.584][192.168.1.200:52433] Server TLS handshake failed. connection closed
info: [15:44:41.584][192.168.1.200:52433] Unable to establish TLS connection with server (connection closed). Trying to establish TLS with client
anyway. If you plan to redirect requests away from this server, consider setting `connection_strategy` to `lazy` to suppress early connections.
warn: [15:44:41.584][192.168.1.200:52433] Client TLS handshake failed. The client may not trust the proxy's certificate for
{AWS ACCOUNT NUMBER}-ats.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com (OpenSSL Error([('SSL routines', '', 'no shared cipher')]))
info: [15:44:41.584][192.168.1.200:52433] server disconnect {AWS ACCOUNT NUMBER}-ats.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:8883
([2406:da00:ff00::3415:cd0c]:8883)


In Wireshark, I see a TCP connection open to AWS and then immediately get a Close Notify. I do not see that client hello that my IoT device sent go out to AWS.
Wireshark Capture

The error is always the same no matter if the key or the certificate can not be read https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/blob/bd39c7b96fd74f0ff83d69acf93898dbcdce9310/mitmproxy/net/tls.py#L173C21-L176. Are you sure the private key is not encrypted? ASN.1 parsing problems usually shouldn't occur even if the format is wrong, ony if the key is encrypted this may happen. I would try to read it using openssl pkcs8 -in private.key from a file that only contains the private key and then together iwth the certificate.

Thanks Robert, my private key originally began with ----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- and I (stupidly) changed it to -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- thinking that was the expected format. Mitmproxy now seems to connect to aws and complete the handshake properly; however, I still get Client TLS handshake failed. The client may not trust the proxy's certificate for {AWS ACCOUNT NUMBER}-ats.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com (OpenSSL Error([('SSL routines', '', 'no shared cipher')])). I saw some posts about ECDSA ciphers not working without a special cert. Ill dig into it next week and report back.

Have you installed the mitmproxy root ca cert in the iot device?
